# Who divides the main memory into page frame?

Tags: memory, memory-management, operating-system, paging, virtual-memory

Who divides the main memory into page frames? From my current understanding it's OS that maintains the frame table, so it's not MMU for this job?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [MMU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_management_unit) is just a hardware thing. Today, it is a part of the CPU chip. Details about the MMU are [instruction set architecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instruction_set_architecture) specific (so different on [x86](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86) and on [PowerPc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PowerPC) or [ARM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ARM_architecture) or [RISC-V](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RISC-V)).

The MMU needs to be configured, to implement suitable [virtual address](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory) to physical address translation.

That MMU configuration (a [privileged](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPU_modes) operation) is done by the operating system [kernel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_(operating_system)) which manages the [page table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_table). From the [user-space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_space) point of view, the OS would provide [system calls](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_call) (such as [mmap(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html) on Linux) to change the [virtual address space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_address_space) of the [process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_(computing)).

Read [*Operating Systems: Three Easy Pieces*](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~remzi/OSTEP/) for more (freely downloadable). There are several [chapters](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~remzi/OSTEP/#book-chapters) (12 to 24) explaining all this.

PS. If you have a Linux system, try the `cat /proc/$$/maps` command (it "shows" the virtual address space of your [shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_shell) process, since your shell would expand `$$` to its pid), and read more about [proc(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html).

Comment: Wow, so can I understand that the MMU provides some (low level) API for the OS to change the configurations right?

Comment: Completely wrong. Sorry, I gave several chapters to read, and you need to read all of them to get a good picture in your brain

Comment: So my "dividing main memory into page frame" is not very clear (although it's the sentence from another book I read), but in reality it's just how MMU interpret the virtual address, right?

Comment: Again, I don't have time and space to explain what takes 12 chapters to be taught. StackOverflow is not the right place for that.

Comment: No need, I'm not understand nothing about these things, and provide only big picture is enough. Thanks for your edit~

Comment: Actually, the picture is probably more complex than what you imagine.

Comment: I understand page table. If you don't mind our conversation will continue. So loader will do the connection between virtual addresses in a page table and physical addresses assigned to a program?

Answer (score 1):

> Who divides the main memory into page frames?

The system hardware divides the main memory into physical page frames.

> From my current understanding it's OS that maintains the frame table, so it's not MMU for this job?

No. The operating system maps a process's logical pages to the physical page frames. The underlying hardware divides the memory into page frames. This may or may not be done by the MMU. It would all depend upon how the chipset is designed.